# What does this regex mean [A-Z0-9._%+-].. Can you help me by answering this

Tags: java, regex

Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9._%+-]")
what does it compiles???

Comment: Have a go and see what it matches:
http://regexr.com/3ddma

Comment: Any regex guide on the web can tell you what is means. Try searching, e.g. using Google. Just try a *smidgen* of **research**, please.

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Answer (score 5):

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-] match a single character present in the list below
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
._%+- a single character in the list ._%+- literally
```

You can use following website to understand and test regex:
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are said to be "compiled", which means that the string of characters is converted to a tree of comparison objects. The tree of comparison objects will be used later to compare with some string (or strings) to see if it matches.

In the case of the regex in your question, it can be interpreted to match any single character that's:

- between A and Z, or
- between 0 and 9, or
- any one of '.', '_', '%', '+', or '-'

This regex is probably for matching url parameters, variable names in a programming language, or something similar.